# how to split the string between two strings in c#?

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, string-parsing

I have one String variable that contains HTML data.Now i want to split that html string into multiple string and then finally merge those strings into single one.

**This is html string:**

```
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #ff0000;"><strong>para1</strong></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #008000;">para2</span> स्द्स्द्सद्स्द para2 again<br /></strong></p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><strong><span style="color: #0000ff;">para3</span><br /></strong></p>
```

**And this is my expected output:**

```
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #ff0000;"><strong>para1</strong></span><strong><span style="color: #008000;">para2</span>para2 again<br /></strong><strong><span style="color: #0000ff;">para3</span><br /></strong></p>
```

My Split Logic is given below...

1. Split the HTML string into token based on `</p>` tag.
2. And take the first token and store it in separate string variable(firstPara).
3. Now take the each and every token and then remove any tag starting with`<p` and also ending with `</p>`.And store each value in separate variable.

4.Then take first token named firstPara and replace the tag `</p>` and then **append** each every token that we got through the **step 3**.

5.So,Now the variable firstPara has whole value...

1. Finally, we just append `</p>` at the end of the firstPara...

This is my problem...

Could you please step me to get out of this issue...

Comment: Use [`Html Agility Pack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) when you need to parse html.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : Thanks for suggesting Html Agility pack for me...Today i learnt very useful one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is regex example how to do it.

```
String pattern = @"(?<=<p.*>).*(?=</p>)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
result.Append("<p>");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    result.Append(match.Value);
}
result.Append("</p>");
```

And this is how you should do it with [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(text);
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
result.Append("<p>");
foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    result.Append(node.InnerHtml);
}
result.Append("</p>");
```

Comment: Shouldn't `<p.*\>` be `<p[^>]*>`?

Comment: it is the same since regex uses greedy search by default

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I know, I just hadn't realized that [lookarounds](http://bit.ly/12cNu13) are [atomic](http://bit.ly/UfRhFg), so I learned something new today. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to split a `string` by another `string`, you may use `string.Split(string[] separator, StringSplitOptions options)` where `separator` is a `string` array which contains at least one string that will be used to split the `string`

**Example**

```
//Initialize a string of name HTML as our HTML code
string HTML = "<p><span style=\"text-decoration: underline; color: #ff0000;\"><strong>para1</strong></span></p> <p style=\"text-align: center;\"><strong><span style=\"color: #008000;\">para2</span> स्द्स्द्सद्स्द para2 again<br /></strong></p> <p style=\"text-align: left;\"><strong><span style=\"color: #0000ff;\">para3</span><br /></strong></p>";
//Initialize a string array of name strSplit to split HTML with </p>
string[] strSplit = HTML.Split(new string[] { "</p>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
//Initialize a string of name expectedOutput
string expectedOutput = "";
string stringToAppend = "";
//Initialize i as an int. Continue if i is less than strSplit.Length. Increment i by 1 each time you continue
for (int i = 0; i < strSplit.Length; i++)
{
    if (i >= 1) //Continue if the index is greater or equal to 1; from the second item to the last item
    {
        stringToAppend = strSplit[i].Replace("<p", "<"); //Replace <p by <
    }
    else //Otherwise
    {
        stringToAppend = strSplit[i]; //Don't change anything in the string
    }
    //Append strSplit[i] to expectedOutput
    expectedOutput += stringToAppend;
}
//Append </p> at the end of the string
expectedOutput += "</p>";
//Write the output to the Console
Console.WriteLine(expectedOutput);
Console.Read();
```

**Output**

```
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #ff0000;"><strong>para1</stro
ng></span> < style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #008000;">p
ara2</span> ?????????????? para2 again<br /></strong> < style="text-align: left;
"><strong><span style="color: #0000ff;">para3</span><br /></strong></p>
```

**NOTICE**: Because my program does not support Unicode characters, it could not read `स्द्स्द्सद्स्द`. Thus, it was translated as `??????????????`.

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: @Saravanan Sorry, about that but I can't really understand your comment. May you please provide what exactly you are trying to do? :)

Comment: I want to replace <p> tages.That means i have only one <p> that will be in html string starting position and one </p> tage that will be in the html string ending position.Not in any other place...

Comment: @Saravanan I've updated my answer. Sorry for misunderstanding. Have a nice day :)